# Python logging class not working when sending stdout to /dev/null

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, nohup, python3

I have a Python 3 script that has logging enabled (for debugging purposes). Whenever I run/execute this script it is working fine and the logfiles are created.

I've also created a setup.sh-bash script to download and install my application. It then automatically starts the script by using *nohup*, in order to make it run on the background. This command is followed by > /dev/null 2>&1 & so it does not output anything to the console. However, this 'bugs' the logging-module from Python, as it can no longer output something to the log-files. It outputs to /dev/null if I'm correct.

I've searched online in order to come up with a solution, but I failed on every try. I hope someone can come up with an idea to this. Maybe I should use something else to make my script run forever (until reboot of course :)) with the possibility to use the Python 3 logging-module and to have no output in the console.

The exact command I'm using to start my script is as follows:

`su -l -s /bin/bash scriptuser -c 'nohup python3 '/etc/scriptroot/main.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &'`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very 'sorry' to say that I have now found the solution myself. It seems that I did not dig deep enough. I am now using daemon-start-stop supported by most UNIX systems, and it's working as it should.

I followed a tutorial on the internet which can be found here: http://blog.scphillips.com/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/

I hope this helps with a lot of other users having the same problem/searching for the same answer.

Thansk for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a result of Python stdout being line buffered. If you run the command with the -u flag it will with unbuffered stdout and stderr:

`su -l -s /bin/bash scriptuser -c 'nohup python3 -u '/etc/scriptroot/main.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &'`

Comment: You cqn improve your answer  by quoting and  linking to a citation for this?